# VBA convert string with day and month name to date

Tags: vba, string, date, type-conversion

I have a `string` of a `date` in french in long format like so:

```
mardi 7 juillet 2020
```

How can I convert it to a date type in VBA ? I tried using `CDate`, `DateValue` and `DateSerial`, but I couldn't figure it out. There must be a way if VBA has a `Long Date` format for dates. I just can't find anyone that was asking this conversion question with this format.

Note that I have a lot of dates since I am looping over many mails so I need a solution that is very general so a solution that takes into account all possible week days (lundi, mardi, ..., dimanche), all possible days 1 to 31 and months Janvier to Décembre and all possible years.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is French your default system locale? What comes out when you try `? formatdatetime(now, vbLongDate)`?

Comment: yes it is so what I get is:   dimanche 18 octobre 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree there should be an easier conversion. This function will strip out the weekday (which is superfluous) and then rely on VBA type conversion to get a Date type (NB. I have only tested this under a English(UK) regional setting).

```
Option Explicit
Public Function DateFromLongFormat(strLongFormatDate As String) As Date
    Dim strDate As String
    strDate = Right(strLongFormatDate, Len(strLongFormatDate) - InStr(1, strLongFormatDate, " "))

    DateFromLongFormat = strDate
End Function
```

Tried it out using a simple test routine on today's date:

```
Sub TestDate()
    Dim strToday As String
    strToday = Format(Now(), "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")

    Dim dt As Date
    dt = DateFromLongFormat(strToday)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! but I think microsoft should alter CDate to be able to take formats into account, bt anyway thanks again !

Comment: I agree ... NB. the constant vbLongDate in FormatDateTime takes the Long date format from your Regional Settings. Eg my settings for "Long date" are "05 April 2017", so that is what I get. Also, from MS pages: "CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. The correct order of day, month, and year may not be determined if it is provided in a format other than one of the recognized date settings. In addition, a long date format is not recognized if it also contains the day-of-the-week string"